# Is there a way to save an HTML div table into a database or anywhere to be accessed from user profile?

Tags: php, html

My program creates an exercise routine in PHP/HTML which generates a bunch of rows from MySQL and puts it into a table to show to the user

```
<html>
   <div class = "exercise" name = "exercise">
     <?php //creates the table ?>
  </div>
</html>
```

The table is also formatted which displays it in a nice way, with each value being put into the code `<table>` and `<tr><td>` etc.

Is there anyway to save "exercise" into somewhere the user can access later e.g. being saved to their profile?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, static HTML is just plain text.
So, a large enough database field (such as MySQL's [TEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) family) could do the job.

Comment: Problem is the table includes things such as a clickable button and a picture, would that still be storable in a text field?

Comment: You never store "pictures" in HTML anyway, just references to them with a URL in a `img` tag. And, buttons are also plain text tags.

Comment: You save it as a string, if you want you can encode it to `base64` to preserve format, but it's about 30% heavier.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t try to save your generated HTML into the user’s profile. Instead, save whatever the user input to generate this exercise routine. For example, let’s say your page asks the user for “length of workout” and “focus on arms or legs?”, and then it generates a table of routines based on a table in MySQL with calculations involving the length and body part of each exercise in the table. All you need to save in the user’s profile is what the user entered: their responses to “length of workout” and “focus on arms or legs?”. Then, when the user views their profile, embed the PHP file you wrote earlier that generates the table, but pass it input from the database instead of from what the user typed.

Maybe you’re thinking this won’t work because your program generates schedules differently every day. For example, the rows in your table are local events that include a date, and you only give the user workouts that happen in the next week. In that case, you can just think of the current date as an input, even though the user doesn’t type it. So you would save “current date”, “length of workout”, and “focus on arms or legs?” to the user’s profile.

By saving only the inputs into the user’s profile rather than the generated HTML, you get a few advantages:

- If you ever come up with a better way to display the exercise schedule and change your PHP code to generate that…

  - The schedule in the user’s profile will be displayed in the new style, rather than the old style.
  - You don’t have to write your CSS styles to be compatible with all versions of schedules you ever saved to a user. Your CSS will only have to be compatible with your current schedule.
- The saved schedules will take up a less space in the database.

The downside is that it will take the computer more time to generate the user’s profile page than if you just included the HTML directly. But I think the advantages above make this worth it.